Limiting authors in bibliography for ieeeconf document
I have a paper I'm looking to submit to RA-L, so I'm using their LaTeX template in Overleaf. I have some references with a large number of authors, so I'd like to shorten them to free up some space.
I found in the bst how-to guide that I can do this by enabling a forced et al setting, which I have done, but I can't get this to actually work. I'm using the ieeetr bib style, abbreviated. Could anyone point to what I'm doing wrong?
Here are the relevant parts of the .tex file:
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4 paper
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                                                                        

\overrideIEEEmargins                     

% Title/Authors

\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Content

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv, IEEEexample} 


\end{document}


The references, IEEEexample.bib, contains each reference with this at the bottom:
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
  CTLuse_article_number     = "yes",
  CTLuse_paper              = "yes",
  CTLuse_forced_etal        = "yes",
  CTLmax_names_forced_etal  = "6",
  CTLnames_show_etal        = "6",
  CTLuse_alt_spacing        = "yes",
  CTLalt_stretch_factor     = "4",
  CTLdash_repeated_names    = "yes",
  CTLname_format_string     = "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}",
  CTLname_latex_cmd         = ""
};

